# How can I expand the entries of a 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I dynamically allocate space for n entries, if I already know the number of columns of a 2d array? I wanted to know the way to doing this without using Lists but I cannot find anything. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
int rows = 200;
int cols = 300;

int[][] mat = new int[rows][cols];
```

You can also read in the row and col from a file, allocate your array and then continue reading the values to populate the array.

The difficulty comes when you don't know the size of the array.  So you need to first, `pre allocate` the array which is a guess.  Then read in as much as you can and continually increase the size until you are done reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.copyOf() function.

Let's say you want to increase size of 4th row in your 2d array with 6 rows.

you could simply, say myArray[3] = Arrays.copyOf(myArray[3], newSize);

Comment: Thank you for answering, however, my question is how can I increase the size of my array dynamically according to the size that it reads from a file

Comment: use FileReader with BufferedReader to read your file and you could use String operations to take out the size you want and assign it to the newSize variable above. That should do.

Comment: @WJS I am afraid I didn't understood what do you mean by "You have to read in values and check and ensure the existing total read does not exceed the current array size. Then adjust the array and continue reading.". I am a newbie too. Could you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I have a file with 5 entries. However, these entries can be either deleted or I can add more that why I need to allocate it dynamically

Comment: Could you please add all these additional information in your question. Your question is really abstract. Now, do you mean, the size array should be number of entries in the file? or each entry represent a size. Could you please clear your question?